# button with custom frame in wpf and blend

Tags: wpf, blend

I want to create a button with custom shape frame in blend or wpf. The goal is to full fill a button with image. how can i do that.I want my button be like the image.

`<Button x:Name="btn_Part3" Content="Button" Margin="107,593,1075,40" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle2}" Click="btn_Part3_Click"/>`

and my style will be

```
<Style x:Key="btn_Part3" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"/>
    <Style x:Key="btn_P3" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Margin="11.673,79.49,155.327,20.51">
                        <Image Source="3.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="68.688,-123.48,43.312,203.98"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="74.688,-119.94,48.188,203.98" Width="10.124" Content="3"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

this is generated by blend
tnx for ur help and srry for bad english

Comment: Sorry for no image.The stackoverflow doesnt let me post the sample image

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong in the code you posted.

I would sincerely suggest you to read more about [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

In order to fix your problem change the ControlTemplate Grid to below. Basically remove all the margins in your control template and set grid background to Transparent. This will fix your problem. But like I suggested you need to read about Styling and Template before you proceed any further after looking at your code.

```
<Grid  Background="Transparent">
                            <Image Source="3.png" Stretch="Fill"  />
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"  Width="10.124" Content="3"/>
                        </Grid>
```

Just to summarise

1. You shouldnt be dragging your controls around in blend to position them. Use proper containers and positioning system (grid, canvas, stackpanels etc)
2. You have triggers in your control template but there are no setters. (You might as well remove the triggers if you are not using them)
3. Again please do some reading :)